# In-app delete Firebase record

Tags: java, android, firebase

Hoping for help on a small issue:

I am trying to delete singular records that are stored in my Firebase database through my Android application.

At present, when clicking the delete button, *all* items are deleted, as opposed to the single record that I have clicked on.

For completeness, I have also included my `updateMaintenance` method, which works perfectly.  As you will see in the `updateMaintenance` method, I have used user-based authentication in `mAuth.getCurrentUser()` - I want to have this for my `deleteMaintenance` method also.

I'm sure this is just a case of adding a small bit of code, but not too sure where to start.  Thanks in advance!

```
private void deleteMaintenance(String maintenanceId) {
    DatabaseReference drMaintenance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("maintenance").child(maintenanceId);

    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    String uid = user.getUid();

    databaseMaintenance.child(uid).removeValue();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Maintenance record has been deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private boolean updateMaintenance(String title, String desc, String id, String primary, String secondary, String property) {

    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("maintenance").child(id);
    Maintenance maintenance = new Maintenance (id, title, desc, primary, secondary, property);

    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    String uid = user.getUid();

    databaseMaintenance.child(uid).child(id).setValue(maintenance);

    databaseReference.setValue(maintenance);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Maintenance Updated Updated Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return true;
}
```

[image: DB Structure]

Comment: what record are u trying to delete?

Comment: So at the moment, when I `onItemLongClick`, I am given the option to delete or update the record that I have clicked on.

Comment: Ok... But I don't know how to delete a single record. Can you shed some light?

Comment: dnt knw which record you are deleting but I mean you can just go one step deeper: `databaseMaintenance.child(uid).child(id).removeValue();` this will remove the child id

Comment: Please add your database structure and highlight us the exact record that you want to delete.

Comment: Updated question.  So I basically want to delete any maintenance record that I chose.

Comment: The code posted doesn't show where 'databaseMaintenance' is set so it can't be known what it's a reference to.   Seems like what you want to use is 'drMaintenance' .

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when using the following line of code:

```
databaseMaintenance.child(uid).removeValue();
```

You are deleting everything that is beneath the `maintenance` -> `uid` node. So basically you are deleting the `uid` node.

To achieve what you want, you need to change the reference. So please change the above line of code with:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
rootRef.child("maintenance").child(uid).child(maintenanceId).removeValue();
```